# What does "conda install package_name" actually do?

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I tried to build and install a simple python package using conda-build and conda install and read many documentions on the internet such as the following:

https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/build-scripts.html
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-build.html
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html

My expection and goal is that after building the tarball using conda-build and then running:

```
cd opt/anaconda3/conda-bld/noarch
conda activate test_env
conda install --use-local my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2
```

that I find my package in opt/anaconda3/envs/python3.8/lib/site-packages/my_test_pkg. However, after the installation finishes the tarball my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2 is only moved to opt/anaconda3/pkgs and extracted there. But there are no files in any site-packages folder of any base or virtual environment. I took look at how other tarballs look like, e.g. pandas. There I found that next to a info directory there is also a lib directory. I suppose that the directory in the tarball needs to match the directory where its content is being distruted to. I took a look at the meta.yaml in pandas but I could not find any info how this "lib" directory in  the tarball is created. Then I tried to manually package and created the same structure as it is in pandas and ran "conda install my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2" again but nothing really happened. So what does conda install actually do?

This is how my meta.yaml looks like

```
{% set version = "0.5.0" %}

package:
  name: my_test_pkg
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  - path: my_test_pkg

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 0

requirements:
  host: 
    - python >=3.8
    - conda >=4.10
    - conda-build
    - anaconda-client
  run:
    - python >=3.8
    - matplotlib >=3.3.2
    - numpy >=1.18 
    - pandas >=1.1.2 

about:
  license: GNU General Public License (GPL)
  summary: 'A package for testing the conda build mechanisms'
```

And this is my build.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Variables
# Actually $CONDA_PREFIX was intended to be used here but it seems that it is overwritten with $BUILD_PREFIX.
dir_in_conda=$SYS_PREFIX/lib/python3.8/site-packages/$PKG_NAME 

# Install
echo "Start installation"
# mkdir $dir_in_conda
# cp -RT $RECIPE_DIR/$PKG_NAME $dir_in_conda
```

As you see I tried also to do the installation in the build.sh script but then I do not know what the "conda install" command is actually for. The output of the conda install command was:

```
conda install --use-local my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2

Downloading and Extracting Packages
my_test_pkg-0.5.0 | ################################################# | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

So what do I need to do and where in order to have my_test_package properly distributed to the conda virtual environment?

UPDATE:
I saw that my info/files and info.paths.json files are empty. But why? I must be doing something wrong during the build process.

**Full stack trace of build process**

```
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.16
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.16
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for my_test_pkg
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for my_test_pkg
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
BUILD START: ['my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    _libgcc_mutex:          0.1-conda_forge           conda-forge
    _openmp_mutex:          4.5-1_gnu                 conda-forge
    anaconda-client:        1.7.2-py_0                conda-forge
    attrs:                  20.3.0-pyhd3deb0d_0       conda-forge
    beautifulsoup4:         4.9.3-pyhb0f4dca_0        conda-forge
    brotlipy:               0.7.0-py39h3811e60_1001   conda-forge
    bzip2:                  1.0.8-h7f98852_4          conda-forge
    ca-certificates:        2020.12.5-ha878542_0      conda-forge
    certifi:                2020.12.5-py39hf3d152e_1  conda-forge
    cffi:                   1.14.5-py39he32792d_0     conda-forge
    chardet:                4.0.0-py39hf3d152e_1      conda-forge
    clyent:                 1.2.2-py_1                conda-forge
    conda:                  4.10.0-py39hf3d152e_1     conda-forge
    conda-build:            3.21.4-py39hf3d152e_0     conda-forge
    conda-package-handling: 1.7.2-py39h38d8fee_0      conda-forge
    cryptography:           3.4.7-py39hbca0aa6_0      conda-forge
    filelock:               3.0.12-pyh9f0ad1d_0       conda-forge
    glob2:                  0.7-py_0                  conda-forge
    icu:                    68.1-h58526e2_0           conda-forge
    idna:                   2.10-pyh9f0ad1d_0         conda-forge
    importlib-metadata:     3.10.0-py39hf3d152e_0     conda-forge
    ipython_genutils:       0.2.0-py_1                conda-forge
    jinja2:                 2.11.3-pyh44b312d_0       conda-forge
    jsonschema:             3.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_3        conda-forge
    jupyter_core:           4.7.1-py39hf3d152e_0      conda-forge
    ld_impl_linux-64:       2.35.1-hea4e1c9_2         conda-forge
    libarchive:             3.5.1-h3f442fb_1          conda-forge
    libffi:                 3.3-h58526e2_2            conda-forge
    libgcc-ng:              9.3.0-h2828fa1_18         conda-forge
    libgomp:                9.3.0-h2828fa1_18         conda-forge
    libiconv:               1.16-h516909a_0           conda-forge
    liblief:                0.10.1-he1b5a44_2         conda-forge
    libstdcxx-ng:           9.3.0-h6de172a_18         conda-forge
    libxml2:                2.9.10-h72842e0_3         conda-forge
    lz4-c:                  1.9.3-h9c3ff4c_0          conda-forge
    lzo:                    2.10-h516909a_1000        conda-forge
    markupsafe:             1.1.1-py39h3811e60_3      conda-forge
    nbformat:               5.1.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    ncurses:                6.2-h58526e2_4            conda-forge
    openssl:                1.1.1k-h7f98852_0         conda-forge
    patchelf:               0.11-he1b5a44_0           conda-forge
    pip:                    21.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    pkginfo:                1.7.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    psutil:                 5.8.0-py39h3811e60_1      conda-forge
    py-lief:                0.10.1-py39hfbd4741_2     conda-forge
    pycosat:                0.6.3-py39h3811e60_1006   conda-forge
    pycparser:              2.20-pyh9f0ad1d_2         conda-forge
    pyopenssl:              20.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    pyrsistent:             0.17.3-py39h3811e60_2     conda-forge
    pysocks:                1.7.1-py39hf3d152e_3      conda-forge
    python:                 3.9.2-hffdb5ce_0_cpython  conda-forge
    python-dateutil:        2.8.1-py_0                conda-forge
    python-libarchive-c:    2.9-py39hf3d152e_2        conda-forge
    python_abi:             3.9-1_cp39                conda-forge
    pytz:                   2021.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    pyyaml:                 5.4.1-py39h3811e60_0      conda-forge
    readline:               8.0-he28a2e2_2            conda-forge
    requests:               2.25.1-pyhd3deb0d_0       conda-forge
    ripgrep:                12.1.1-h516909a_1         conda-forge
    ruamel_yaml:            0.15.80-py39h3811e60_1004 conda-forge
    setuptools:             49.6.0-py39hf3d152e_3     conda-forge
    six:                    1.15.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0       conda-forge
    soupsieve:              2.0.1-py_1                conda-forge
    sqlite:                 3.35.4-h74cdb3f_0         conda-forge
    tk:                     8.6.10-h21135ba_1         conda-forge
    tqdm:                   4.60.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    traitlets:              5.0.5-py_0                conda-forge
    tzdata:                 2021a-he74cb21_0          conda-forge
    urllib3:                1.26.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    wheel:                  0.36.2-pyhd3deb0d_0       conda-forge
    xz:                     5.2.5-h516909a_1          conda-forge
    yaml:                   0.2.5-h516909a_0          conda-forge
    zipp:                   3.4.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    zlib:                   1.2.11-h516909a_1010      conda-forge
    zstd:                   1.4.9-ha95c52a_0          conda-forge

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Copying /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/my_test_pkg/my_test_pkg to /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work/
source tree in: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work
export PREFIX=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_place
export BUILD_PREFIX=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/_build_env
export SRC_DIR=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work
Start installation

Resource usage statistics from building my_test_pkg:
   Process count: 1
   CPU time: Sys=0:00:00.0, User=-
   Memory: 3.3M
   Disk usage: 36B
   Time elapsed: 0:00:02.1


Packaging my_test_pkg
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging my_test_pkg
INFO conda_build.build:build(2274): Packaging my_test_pkg
Packaging my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0
INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0
INFO conda_build.build:bundle_conda(1514): Packaging my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0
No files or script found for output my_test_pkg
WARNING:conda_build.build:No files or script found for output my_test_pkg
WARNING conda_build.build:bundle_conda(1613): No files or script found for output my_test_pkg
number of files: 0
Fixing permissions
INFO :: Time taken to mark (prefix)
        0 replacements in 0 files was 0.00 seconds
TEST START: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/noarch/my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2
Adding in variants from /tmp/tmpw7306v3x/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from /tmp/tmpw7306v3x/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
INFO conda_build.variants:_combine_spec_dictionaries(234): Adding in variants from /tmp/tmpw7306v3x/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
Nothing to test for: /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/noarch/my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2
Renaming work directory '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work' to '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work_moved_my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop'
INFO:conda_build.utils:Renaming work directory '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work' to '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work_moved_my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop'
INFO conda_build.utils:shutil_move_more_retrying(2077): Renaming work directory '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work' to '/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work_moved_my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop'
shutil.move(work)=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work, dest=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work_moved_my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop)
INFO:conda_build.utils:shutil.move(work)=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work, dest=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work_moved_my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop)
INFO conda_build.utils:shutil_move_more_retrying(2084): shutil.move(work)=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work, dest=/home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/my_test_pkg_1617828659204/work_moved_my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0_linux-64_main_build_loop)
# Automatic uploading is disabled
# If you want to upload package(s) to anaconda.org later, type:


# To have conda build upload to anaconda.org automatically, use
# conda config --set anaconda_upload yes
anaconda upload \
    /home/filip/Dokumente/Programming/build_python_package/conda-build/noarch/my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0.tar.bz2
anaconda_upload is not set.  Not uploading wheels: []

INFO :: The inputs making up the hashes for the built packages are as follows:
{
  "my_test_pkg-0.5.0-py_0": {
    "recipe": {}
  }
}


####################################################################################
Resource usage summary:

Total time: 0:02:26.9
CPU usage: sys=0:00:00.0, user=0:00:00.0
Maximum memory usage observed: 3.3M
```

Comment: So now you have it installed. I don't use `conda`, but on `pip` you just have to import it and it works.

Comment: It is not really installed because I cannot find it anywhere. Maybe it is because I did not build it properly but I cannot find any documentation how to build the tarball so that it has the same directory structure as in the conda directory

Comment: Have you tried importing it?

Comment: yes I have and it is not recognized. But as I wrote in the update the info/files is completely empty, so it is not properly built (see build stack trace) and I do not know what can I change in my meta.yaml

Comment: Do you have a `setup.py` in your package? Most pure Python packages don't need separate `build.sh` - a simple `script: python setup.py install` in the recipe is usually sufficient (see [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#script)). Also, `conda`, `conda-build` and `anaconda-client` shouldn't be host requirements; but probably need `setuptools`.